# Notifications combined with BroadcastIntents are stale , how to freshen them?

Tags: android

I am sending notifications out from a BroadcastIntentReceiver, however, when I click on the notification, it is from a few broadcasts ago.

I'm using this pattern, however, I do not believe that cancelAll() works. If it did, then wouldn't the fresh Broadcasts be getting their information into these notifs??

```
mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
mNotificationManager.notify(3, intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept in Android of a `Notification` being "stale".

I am going to take the educated guess that what you really meant to say was:

> I created a Notification with a PendingIntent wrapped around an Intent that contained some extras. Later on, I updated or re-raised that same Notification on a PendingIntent for the same basic Intent but with new extras. Now, however, when I tap on the Notification, I see the original extras, not the current ones.

If so, you need to use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` when creating the `PendingIntent` (e.g., `getActivity()`).